# Configuring Routes asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am building an angularJS application with a asp.net webapi backend.  In my routeconfig file, i have this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works fine.  Any Url that is called is returned the Home/Index view (the only view i have) to the application, and angularJS works out if there is a querystring and works out which state to show.

I have the basic Get, Put, Post and Delete methods in my WebApi, and i can call them fine.  Examples are

```
public class CompanyController : ApiController
{
    private CompanyService _service;

    public CompanyController(CompanyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        ...

        return Ok(model);
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        ...

        return Ok(model);
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(CompanyModel model)
    {
        ...

        return Ok();
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(Company model)
    {
        ...

        return Ok();
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(CompanyModel model)
    {
        ...

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Now i would like to add another method to my api, where the user can load companies, but also pass in a term to search for (a string), a pageSize (int) and a page number (int).  Something like this

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string term, int page, int pageSize) {
    ...

    return Ok(results);
}
```

Now i understand that i need to add another route, to make sure this method can be called.  Fine, so i add this to my RouteConfig.

```
// search
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "search",
    url: "api/{controller}/{page}/{pageSize}/{term}",
    defaults: new { page = @"\d+", pageSize = @"\d+", term = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Why doesnt this work??  I got a resource cannot be found error, when trying to call it via postman using the url localhost/api/company/1/10/a, where 1 = page, 10 = pageSize and a = term

Its probably a simple answer, but new to MVC so still learning.

Comment: Use Route Attribute if you are working with Web API 2. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You are using Get method, which means you can pass your search option via Url, so you can create a search option object like :

```
public class SearchOptions
{
   public string Term{get; set;}
   public int Page {get; set;}
   public int PageSize {get; set;}
}
```

then you can change your method to be like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/blabla/SearchSomething")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromUri]SearchOptions searchOptions) {
    ...

    return Ok(results);
}
```

Notice the Route attribute that I've decorated the method by, you can use different constraints for the method parameters, have a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Finally you can call the method from the client like this

```
api/blabla/SearchSomething?term=somevalue&page=1&pageSize=10
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank u. Will check it out. In ur example how would u call that get method? I am not sure about the fromurl part?

Comment: [FromUri] tells the model binder to construct the SearchOptions from the query string not from the request body, so you need to pass your search options with the querystring. see this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api